# How do I publish my first Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, publish

I've built a website which I'm serving through a basic Node.js server that I've built as well.

I've created a ***mysitename*** folder which itself contains a ***public*** folder (containing all the .html, .css etc. files) as well as a server.js file (my server). I call node server.js from inside ***mysitename*** folder and everything is working fine on `localhost:8080`

Now I want to publish it (in a dev environment, i.e. the URL would look something like this : http://mysitename.someservice.com) so that I can test it live.

I tried **heroku**.com but they couldn't have made the process of setting up my app to serve through them more confusing. It's so **confusing** it's ridiculous.

I thought that it was just a matter of uploading this ***mysitename*** folder online and then using some service to execute server.js

Is there a **simpler**, more "**out-of-the-box**" free service I could use and definitely less of the maze heroku appears to be, or is there a **better step-by-step guide**, at least, on how to do that using Heroku ?

I followed the steps on the Heroku site, created a BitBucket Account and a repo with the folder I mentioned above and then I installed Source Tree but by the time I got to the last step nothing was working. I know I'm mentioning Heroku but I'd rather stay away from that riddle if there's a cleaner way of doing things.

This is the first time I try to publish a site (let alone a site being served through my own server) so I would really appreciate the help as I'm completely in the dark right now.

If this is not the forum for such a question please let me know and I'll remove it and then search elsewhere.

Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: You might look into Nodejitsu, but don't construe that as an endorsement.  I have not used either Heroku or Nodejitsu to deploy a Node app.

Comment: What have you used instead?

Comment: I've only been creating node apps on local VMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you **roll your own server**, you'll have a lot more control and flexibility to experiment/make mistakes.

As you seem to be a beginner, you'll be able to learn at your own pace without being limited by the platform you're using. For example, Heroku's read-only filesystem, PostgreSQL database, etc...

What I'd suggest is to use Amazon EC2. The reason is simple, they give you a free instance for a year, it's like having a free PC in the cloud for you to play with. (No I'm not affiliated to amazon, just remembering the joy I experienced when I was just started and found that out).

You'll find a great tutorial here to deploy your first instance, it'll save you a few hours of research time.

[Tutorial](http://www.lauradhamilton.com/how-to-set-up-a-nodejs-web-server-on-amazon-ec2)

Once your server is setup, grab a cheap domain name from godaddy or namecheap, and point it to your server's IP. Your site will be up and running in no time, for about 3$ total.

The whole process is very easy to do, and will give you far more knowledge than using one or the other online solutions. As a bonus, you will be able to run all sorts of things on your instance, while keeping your website alive.

And for all your problems, there is Stack Overflow.

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: wow thank you so much for this xShirase - I was just reading a "Heroku Vs. AWS Elastic Beanstalk" article and the comparisons were confusing me even more. The conclusion was that for a small app I should start off with and learn Heroku. However, your suggestion makes much more sense given that I'm a beginner. I'll checkout EC2 now and thanks for taking the time to clarify the steps I need to take now one by one. :-)